# vTaskStartScheduler is not working in Keil uVision 5 with FreeRTOS

Tags: c, stm32, freertos, keil, nucleo

I'm working with Keil uVision and freeRTOS by first time, but I don't know why once a load the code to my board (Nucleo-F302R8) it is not working.

I'm working with the following, for testing I'm just trying to blink two LEDs, and I'm trying to keep it standalone (not using Cube). Looking for a solution I found that some people had missing

`/* Map the FreeRTOS port interrupt handlers to their CMSIS standard names. */ #define xPortPendSVHandler                    PendSV_Handler #define vPortSVCHandler                       SVC_Handler #define xPortSysTickHandler                   SysTick_Handler`

But in my case this was already included, also I saw that I needed to change #define configUSE_TIMERS from 0 to 1.

```
#include "stm32f3xx.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"

const TickType_t xDelay = 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS;

void vLED1Task(void *pvParameters);
void vLED2Task(void *pvParameters);



void vLED1Task(void *pvParameters)
{
   

     while(1)
     {
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_13;

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(500));

        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_13;

        vTaskDelay(xDelay);

    }
}

void vLED2Task(void *pvParameters)
{
    

     while(1)
     {
        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS_14;

        vTaskDelay(xDelay);

        GPIOB->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR_14;

        vTaskDelay(xDelay);


            
    }
}

int main(void)
{
 RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOBEN;
 GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER13_0;
 GPIOB->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER14_0;

 xTaskCreate(vLED1Task, "LED1Task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, configMAX_PRIORITIES - 1, NULL);
 xTaskCreate(vLED2Task, (const portCHAR *)"LED2_Task", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, NULL);

 vTaskStartScheduler();  
    
  
}
```